# How can I change loading screen/beginning of match tips in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

In loading screen and in the beginning of a match there are various tips shown (they are the same per game). Since they are mostly basic ones, I'd like to change them to some generic tips I'd not remember most times.

Is there somewhere to edit loading screen tips?

Comment: If you're interested, the reason for Riot displaying these tips is a psychological trick called "priming". You can see more about it (and the results they've collected) in this video: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/191262/

Comment: This one is even more informative on this topic http://www.punchingsnakes.com/?p=771

Still, sad that there is no overwrite possibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No you can't customise the loading screen tips as they are server sided and not client sided.